# Excel: Avoid formula error checking when using replace all

Tags: excel

I've been having a very annoying problem with a large excel file in which I need to replace all the ";" by ",". When I try to do this I get an error (That function isn't valid) that I've discovered that is caused by a leading "@" that is present in some of the cells, so I try to replace all the "@" by "'@" but I get this error: There is a problem with this formula..., beacause there are cells with leading "=", If I try replacing the "=" by "'=" I get the same error than before beacuse of course there are still cells with a leading "@" and I can't do the replace by "'@" again beacause then I'll start getting multiple "'" before the "@" (each time you run the "replace all" it starts from the begining of course) and I need to maintain the integrity of the data. So, is there any way to avoid the formula error checking when doing a replace? I've tryed going to more commands -> Formulas and uncheking "Enable background error checking" and setting "Workbook Calculation" to manual, but I haven't got any luck.

Comment: Can you please post a couple of lines of sample data?

Comment: I've already found a workarround, but in case it helps someone else: there are multiple columns like this =asdasdadsad and some others like this @adasdasdadas, the thing is that when I try the replace "=" by "'=" when excel founds the first column starting by "@" throws an error and stops replacing, same for when I try doing the replace of "@" by "'@", and since every time you run the "replace all" starts replacing from the begining, it replaces again the "=" and "@" already changed, so you end up having this characters with an  indeterminate number of "'".

Comment: You mean the cells with the problem? yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem was in fact only in a column, I created an additional one next to it and did

```
="'"&A1
```

And then dragged the value across the column. That solved it for me.